# what is the query to return Name and Salary of employee Having Max Salary

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

1. what is the query to return Name and Salary of employee Having Max Salary

Comment: Could you please update the question with the list of columns in the `EMPLOYEE` table?  Otherwise, we're guessing column names...  Knowing the database would be nice, too.

Comment: I added tag `greatest-n-per-group`.  Follow that tag to find many examples of the solution.

Comment: What should it return in the presense of two equally paid employees that have the highest salary?

Answer (score 19):

```
SELECT Name, Salary FROM Minions
WHERE Salary = (SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Minions)
```

Note that this will return more than one row if there is more than one employee who have the same max salary

Answer (score 4):

```
select name, salary from (select * from salary_table order by salary desc limit 1)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you but that assumes using MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQLite - won't work on Oracle or SQL Server.  Also, don't need the subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If only the person who down-voted explained why :)

Comment: I prefer to comment & discuss long before I downvote.  The query is correct for the databases I mentioned, but a tad overcomplicated.  Seeing everyone else is providing vendor specific answers, +1

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT FirstName, max(salary)
FROM Employees 
WHERE salary = (
                SELECT max(salary)
                FROM employees
               )
GROUP BY FirstName
```

working in SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 1):

A couple of proprietary solutions

```
SELECT TOP 1 [WITH ties] Name, Salary
FROM employee
ORDER BY  Salary DESC


SELECT Name, Salary
FROM employee
ORDER BY  Salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And a standard one

```
WITH E AS
(
    SELECT Name, Salary, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) RN /*Or RANK() for ties*/
    FROM employee
)
SELECT Name, Salary FROM E WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Interestingly, all of these seem to ignore the fact that there could be more than one employee with the maximum salary value.  Of course, the question did ask for an "employee" but it could really be "employees".

Answer (score 1):

In case there are multiple rows with the same **MAX** number then you can just limit the number to desired number like this

```
SELECT Name, Salary FROM Minions
WHERE Salary = (SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Minions) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select e.name, e.salary from employee e where
  not exists (select salary from employee e1 where e.salary < e1.salary)
```

This will of course return more than one record if there are multiple people with the max salary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an oracle database and only want a single "employee" then:

```
SELECT MAX( name   ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY salary ASC ) AS name,
       MAX( salary ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY salary ASC ) AS salary
FROM   Minions;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d287/1/0)

(kudos to Neil N for his table name)

- SQL Server has a similar `FIRST_VALUE` (or `LAST_VALUE`) analytic function.
- PostgreSQL also supports window functions including `LAST_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

These type of queries (grouped operaions) can execute with sub query.
Example

```
select *from emp where sal=(max(sal)from emp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one employee has maximum salary

SQL Server:

```
select top 1 name, salary
from employee
order by salary desc
```

Oracle:

```
select name, salary
from employee
order by salary desc
limit 1
```

Above queries scans the table only once unlike other queries using subqueries.