# error in Max count(*) in SQL with same data

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I wrote a SQL query to get users with the largest number of purchases.

```
SELECT name, count(*) as C
FROM sells
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY C
LIMIT 1
```

But, If i have two users with same number of purchase this query can not detect. what's the solution?

Comment: if both users have the same number of purchase, max is the same for both. You need an extra criteria to define which to pick. For instance, smallest user_id (that in the case you have to get only one user)

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I think he wants to select both rows.

Comment: The solution depends on what result you need, only one user (according to some additional criteria), or all users with largest number of purchases

Comment: You need to create a nested SQL statement which will find the largest number of purchase from the dataset in the internal query and then use that value to see which User has that value.
See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355744/what-is-the-query-to-return-name-and-salary-of-employee-having-max-salary)

Comment: What is the result in case of a query with a where condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try subquery:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as C
FROM sells
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING C >= ALL 
    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM sells
     GROUP BY user_id)
```

This will work in any sql version, without using `LIMIT` in a subquery

Comment: Barmar's answer may be faster; `ALL` is likely requiring every `C` from the outer query to be compared to every `count(*)` from the subquery (_O(N^2)_); a `LIMIT`ed subquery would compare every `C` to just the largest `count(*)` (_O(2N)_).

Answer (score 2):

Write a subquery that gets the maximum count. Then use `HAVING` to select all the rows with that count.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM sells
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING c = (SELECT COUNT(*) c
            FROM sells
            GROUP BY user_id
            ORDER BY c DESC
            LIMIT 1)
```

or this can be done as a join between subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS c
      FROM sells
      GROUP BY user_id) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
      FROM sells
      GROUP BY user_id
      ORDER BY c DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t2
ON t1.c = t2.c
```

Comment: This (limit in subqueries) is not supported in all MySQL versions

Comment: If it's not supported, it can be converted to a join.

Comment: This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support

Comment: I've added the join version.

Comment: Then try ``>=ALL`` query

Comment: @Barmar it still contains ``LIMIT`` in a subquery

Comment: @Dimgold judging from MySQL and MariaDB documentation; those should be fine. He is not using "IN/ALL/ANY/SOME" in either query; it's possible it works faster than the ALL version you've put forth.

Comment: @Uueerdo Ive refered my version of the solution. Previous MySQL versions dont support ordering and limiting in subqueries

Comment: @Dimgold My understanding is that the restriction only applies when the subquery is used along with the operators mentioned in the above comment. There's no restriction when the subquery is used in a `JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar just confirmed it on a server I have running, there should be no issues with either of your answers; if you had using `IN` instead of `=` there would have been an issue. _You could even have used `>=` without `ALL` and been fine._

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM sells
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT MAX(C) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM sells GROUP BY user_id ) )
```

Comment: Limit in subquery is not supported in all MySQL versions

Comment: see my version - without a double subquery

Answer (score 1):

You are using `LIMIT 1` in the query. It restricts the number of records in the output to one. If you wish to see all the records from the output remove this `LIMIT`.

If you only need to see one row per every same count, you can modify this query as:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name), count(*) as C
FROM sells
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY C
LIMIT 1
```

This will concatenate both the names having similar counts.

Comment: Wont give the needed result (grouping by each user)